# How to solve android configuration error?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-ide

Every time i'm getting a 'Module not specified' error in my run config while creating a new project.
What is reason for this error and why every time it's showing?
I don't know why it's showing every time.
How to resolve this type of error?